# How to make php post loop with category icons

Tags: php, wordpress

So basically, I'm working on a custom wordpress theme. What i'm trying to do is to set an icon for each category. If the loop starts and the post has a category, It'll show up with the icon that it has assigned. Right now it shows the correct icons, but the title and exerpt of the post keeps changing to the name of the page. Here is an example I have three posts math, english and history all of them have the correct icon, but display the name blog post page instead of math, english, or history.

```
<?php /* Template Name: News Blog Page */ get_header(); ?>
<div id="blog-post-wrapper" class="section_wrapper">
<div class="column three-fourth">
    <?php $currentPage = get_query_var('paged');
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'order' => 'DESC', 
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'paged' => $currentPage
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if($the_query -> have_posts()): 
            while ($the_query -> have_posts()): $the_query -> the_post();
                get_template_part('postloopcontent', get_post_format());
            endwhile;
        echo "<div class='pagination'>";
           echo paginate_links(array(
                'total' => $the_query -> max_num_pages
            ));
        echo "</div>";
        endif;
    ?>
</div>
<div class="column one-fourth">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

the top one is my basic layout and it grabs my loop. the bottom one is my loop

```
<?php

// Standard Post Format

?>



  <?php $bgImage = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
  <div class="column one-third" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $bgImage; ?>);">

          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="nws-img">
              <?php

                // Find the first category the post is in.
                $categories = get_the_category();
                $category = $categories[ 0 ]->term_id;

                $imgargs = array(
                    'cat' => $category,
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'posts_per_page' => '1'
                );

                $imgquery = new WP_Query( $imgargs );

            if ( $imgquery->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $imgquery->have_posts() ) {  $imgquery->the_post();  ?>
                    <div class="category-featured-image">
                        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            // Reset postdata to restore ordinal query.
            wp_reset_postdata();

        ?>
        </a>
    <div id="content-box">
        <h1> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" > <?php the_title(); ?> </a> </h1>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop file, you're resting post data i.e. `wp_reset_postdata();` outside the `$imgquery` loop/condition. If you could wrap the postdata rest function inside the condition, I think that should work.

You code must look like this

```
<?php

// Standard Post Format

?>



  <?php $bgImage = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
  <div class="column one-third" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $bgImage; ?>);">

          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="nws-img">
              <?php

                // Find the first category the post is in.
                $categories = get_the_category();
                $category = $categories[ 0 ]->term_id;

                $imgargs = array(
                    'cat' => $category,
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'posts_per_page' => '1'
                );

                $imgquery = new WP_Query( $imgargs );

            if ( $imgquery->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $imgquery->have_posts() ) {  $imgquery->the_post();  ?>
                    <div class="category-featured-image">
                        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                // Reset postdata to restore ordinal query.
                wp_reset_postdata();
            }

        ?>
        </a>
    <div id="content-box">
        <h1> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" > <?php the_title(); ?> </a> </h1>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well thank you on the last part, the change did work, but the issue now is with this:
    <div id="content-box">
        <h1> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" > <?php the_title(); ?> </a> </h1>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

The permalink grabs the link for the current page and the title is doing the exact same thing. So instead of displaying the link or title of the post, it displays the link of the current page and the title.